# What would be the Primary key?

Tags: database-design, nhibernate-mapping

I have a question about Database design.
I have two tables, usertable and historytable, which are one-to-many relationship, which usertable contains

- username primary key
- passwordname
- email

and historytable has

- username foreign key
- date
- visted url

I am not sure if there are any negative effects in terms of performance if historytable has no primary key defined , if there are , what would be the best option in the historytable to be the primary key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to define a new column: UserHistoryId
Make it identity column

The reason for this is no combination of the other columns could be unique in all cases.

e.g. If a history record is created twice in one day for a user from the same url.

Performance:

Depends on how the history table is used - If you only ever SELECT data from it by means of a query on userId, or date, or Url, then the ID column would serve no purpose.

However, if you ever perform any Update/Delete operations on the table then, the Id would be useful.

Regardless of current requirements, it costs you almost nothing to include the extra column now, and it's something I would always recommend.

Comment: Thanks, accepted. The modification on the historytable is necessary, but I do not understand how would the Id be useful?

Comment: Say you select an item from the table via the userId, then decide to delete one item, or update one item - you would use the Id to perform the operation - even if you don't do this now, you may in the future. Regardless imho it's good practice to always have a primary key even if it's a surrogate.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't see an obvious primay key then just add an auto-incremending integer /identity column as your primary key - this goes for almost *any* table.

There may be a couple of situations where there is a better choice, but most of the time an auto-increment integer field is a good choice of primary key regardless.

In fact I would probably recommend an auto-incrementing integer / identity column as the primary key for your users table too - there are a couple of situations (e.g. deleted users) where you might want to have two rows with the same username.

Answer (score 1):

you could check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230351/what-should-i-consider-when-selecting-a-data-type-for-my-primary-key/232985#232985). Though this question is more generic than yours, it should give you a wider view on what should be primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the likely key of the history table would be (username, date, url). This is only a guess based on the names of the attributes however. You should determine the keys based on business analysis and your requirements.

Comment: This is certainly an option, but i doubt that i have ever use a long size primary key (such as url) as the IO process.

Comment: The question is what information do you want to represent in this table? In other words, what identifies this type of fact. The size of a URL is a different question.